# How do I get a list of all enabled media in Mageia via CLI?

Tags: repository, administration

I have read [URPMI](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/URPMI) from Mageia wiki but there seems to be no mention of how I can check the currently enabled media using `urpmi` command. There is `urpmi.addmedia` and `urmpi.removemedia`. So I tried doing `urpmi.listmedia` but it obviously isn't an existing command.

Any way I can check this? Do note that I don't have any `X Windows` installed so I need to do this via command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the file `/etc/urpmi/urpmi.cfg` works as @slafat01 mentioned.

There is also the command:

```
[user@localhost ~]# urpmq --list-media
...<list of media>...
```

From `man urpmq`

```
--list-media [type]
    List available media. You can optionally add a type selector: all will list all
    media (the default), update to list update media, or active to list only
    active media.
```

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking for is /etc/urpmi/urpmi.cfg.  If the file is not enabled, the entry will list 'ignore' as an option.  If it does not state 'ignore', then it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, here are all possibilities:

`urpmq --dump` will show the interpreted configuration from /etc/urpmi/urpmi.cfg , one repo per line:

`[doktor5000@Mageia4 ~]$ urpmq --dump
local-noarch /home/doktor5000/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch 
local /home/doktor5000/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64 
"Core Release (distrib1)" http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/mageia/distrib/4/x86_64/media/core/release 
--update "Core Updates (distrib3)" http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/mageia/distrib/4/x86_64/media/core/updates
[...snip...]
--update google-chrome http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64`

Another useful one would be `urpmq --list-media active --list-url` which will show all currently active repos including complete URLs so you see which mirror is used.
This is partly mentioned on the wiki page you cited: [urpmq](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/URPMI#urpmq)

`[doktor5000@Mageia4 ~]$ urpmq --list-media active --list-url
local-noarch /home/doktor5000/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch
Core Release (distrib1) http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/mageia/distrib/4/x86_64/media/core/release
[...snip...]
google-chrome http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64`

If you're using the default [$MIRRORLIST mechanism](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Installing_and_removing_software#Adding_a_specific_Media_Mirror) then it's a little harder to show the chosen mirror.
`urpmq --sources rpm` will work, this shows the complete URL for any given package. 
`$ urpmq --sources rpm
http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/mageia/distrib/4/x86_64/media/core/release/rpm-4.11.1-8.mga4.x86_64.rpm`

You can also grep the mirror cache file to see which mirror has been chosen `grep chosen /var/cache/urpmi/mirrors.cache`

All these methods should be easier then directly looking at `/etc/urpmi/urpmi.cfg`

If you want to see more tips about urpmi and rpm, check our [MAQeia about software & package management hints](https://forums.mageia.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=4231)